# BOGOF not working on magento store

Tags: cart, shopping-cart-price-rules

///////////UPDATED QUESTION/////////////

Ok i found the reason it wasn't working it because i was selecting "general" as a customer group, and it doesnt include non-logged in customers as "general" Do you know if there is a way to make this rule apply to everyone in all groups included not logged in??

///////////UPDATED QUESTION/////////////

I created a Shopping cart rule for buy one get one free with these actions

Apply:Percentage of product price discount

Discount Amount * : 50

Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To:0

Discount Qty Step (Buy X):2

Apply to Shipping Amount:no

Free Shipping:no

Stop Further Rules Processing:no

and the condition:
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
SKU  is  1526.

but it is not doing anything to that product when i get to my shopping cart.

so i added this under the conditions tab
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true: 
SKU  is  1526.

But still nothing is happening. So i was wondering do i need to do anything after the rule like reindex, clear cache or does it take a while to kick in or am i just doing it wrong??

Thank you

Comment: So you have 3 items of sku 1526 in the cart, they are **simple products** and no discount?

Comment: even if i add a voucher code it says the voucher code is invalid

Comment: The misunderstanding here is you need to add "free" item manually. Not very convenient, i agree with you.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the condition tab?  Change action to just fixed discount for whole cart and try the voucher again?

Comment: Yes, magento will not automatically add products to cart unless you are using some plugin like "auto add promo items" from magento connect

Comment: I changed it to fixed discount, took out all conditions and when i entered the code it still didnt work. When i get onto a computer where the print screen button works i will post a pic of the original rule

Comment: Ok i found the reason it wasn't working it because i was selecting "general" as a customer group, and it doesnt include non-logged in customers as "general" Do you know if there is a way to make this rule apply to everyone in all groups included not logged in??

Comment: Select all groups, its multiselect field, not just one vlaue

Comment: Thank you for replying throughout the day you was a big help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all groups with ctrl + mouse click. It's multiselect field.

Comment: Dont know why i didnt think of doing that haha. Thank you